# Python - Flask API response cant json_decode

Tags: php, python, json, flask

I have built a very simple `Python` `API` using `flask`, my response looks like this...

```
response = {
    "id" : "345345d",
    "topdata" : {
        "top"    : 234,
        "left"   : 42,
    },
    "bottomdata" : {
        "color" : "red",
        "bg" : "black",
    },
}

return jsonify(response)
```

I then try and decode that response in my PHP script like this...

```
$response = json_decode($response);
```

But this gives me the following error..

```
Cannot use object of type stdClass as array
```

Anyone any ideas where I am going wrong?

Comment: Did you try examining the contents of `$response` before sending it to `json_decode`? Does it look like valid JSON? Does it look like what you expected it to be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) has a 2nd argument to return an array:

```
$response = json_decode($response, true);
```

Comment: Thanks, that fixed things

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
json_decode($response->result_array());
```